# Is there a way in atom to automatically create implementations for header functions?

Tags: c++, linux, atom-editor

I use the utility Visual Studio provides for which you can just select the 3 member function declarations in this class,

```
class class1
{
   int thing1(int a, int b);
   int thing2(int c);
   void thing3(int d);
};
```

and right clicking gives you an option to create empty definitions for them

```
int class1::thing1(int a, int b) { }
int class1::thing2(int c) { } 
void class1::thing3(int d) { }
```

It was very convenient to have this, but I'm using Atom now. Is there an equivalent to this on Atom?

Comment: Note that this question is asking how to use a specific programming tool, to do a specific task. The question is on-topic, and is not "Seeking Recommendations".

Comment: My bad. Is there any particular tag or site I should use next time for these types of questions?

Comment: You can ask these kinds of questions here. Note that asking for packages for an editor is off-topic as it is a software recommendation. It's helpful to add the tag for the editor/tool you're asking about, e.g. the one that was added for you in this question.

Comment: I tried to add the atom tag and couldn't, but I guess the atom-editor one would have done the trick. Didn't think of that.